# How do I make smoother movement?

Tags: java, swing, game-physics, paintcomponent

So I need help to make my character move more smoothly.
The problem is that the character moves one pixel when I press a key and after like one second he runs "smoothly" after that. How can I fix it so that I don't need to wait that one second and he just runs smoothly from the beginning?
I appreciate any help and thanks before hand!

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
    update();
}
private boolean[] KB = new boolean[4];
public void update(){ 
    if(KB[0] = true)
    {
        y -= 10;
    }
    if(KB[1] = true)
    {
        x -= 10;
    }
    if(KB[2] = true)
    {
        y += 10;
    }
    if(KB[3] = true)
    {
        x +=10;
    }
    repaint();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        KB[0] = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        x -= 10;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        y += 10;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        x += 10;
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
```

Comment: `if(KB[0] = true)` should be `if(KB[0] == true)` ? or just `if(KB[0])`

Comment: And why do you have a different logic in `keyPressed` ? PS : Calling repaint() in `paintComponent` is probably not the best idea either

Comment: You need to use a `Swing Timer` to control the animation. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). The `KeyboardAnimation.java` example shows how to use a `Swing Timer` for smooth animation that you can control.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using `KeyListener` and recommand using the [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it will solve the focus related issus with `KeyListener` and provide a much more reusable solution.

`keyPressed` will also have an initial delay when it's first pressed, between the first and repeating key strokes, this can be overcome by setting a flag when the key is pressed and released.  See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856918/how-to-eliminate-delay-in-keypress/24857086#24857086) for more details

Don't call `update` in your `paintComponent`, painting may occur for any number of reasons, may of which you don't control, this could cause issues with maintaining a smooth animation.

Instead you need a "main" loop which is responsible for updating the state and scheduling repaints.  As a simple solution, you could use a Swing `Timer` to do this, as it's to update the state of the UI from within without risking additional threading issues

Have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

As has already been stated, use `if(KB[0])` over `if(KB[0] = true)`, as `=` is an assignment, not a evalution.  Using the first form eliminates the possibility of accidentally making these kind og mistakes

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `update` method is incorrect. You use the `=` operator instead of `==` in your condition.

```
if (KB[0] = true)
```

will assign `true` to `KB[0]` and evaluate it as `true`, Therefore all your values will be set to true inside your `if`. Change `=` to `==` when you use it as a condition unless you want to assign the value.

Comment: Ahh I see Thanks! It helped me out! btw do you know how I can use a timer in my code while your at it? would appreciate it since my teacher wants me to have one :D

Comment: @MushiMushi you are welcome and you could take a look at this small tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html. If my answer helped you solve your problem, then you might want to accept it as the correct answer.